# Python pass by object reference value

Tags: python, pass-by-name

I'm trying to write an algorithm in python to print out all paths from the root of a (binary) tree to each leaf. Here's my code:

```
def fb_problem(node, curr_trav):
    curr_trav = curr_trav + [node]

    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        for path_node in curr_trav:
            print path_node.data 
        print "XXX"

    if node.left is not None:
        fb_problem(node.left, curr_trav)
    if node.right is not None:
        fb_problem(node.right, curr_trav)

fb_problem(root, [])
```

I keep a list of nodes in the current traversal, and when I've reached a leaf, I print out the list. I'm misunderstanding something about the way python passes objects though. I *thought* that as each recursive call completes and is popped off the stack, the original `curr_trav` variable would not be affected by what the recursive call did. However, it seems as if the line

```
curr_trav += [node]
```

Is mutating the original list. The `+=` operator returns a new list, as opposed to `.append()`, which actually mutates the original object. So shouldn't this call just be reassigning the name given to the object in the function, not mutating the original object? When I change the line to something like

```
t_trav = curr_trav += [node]
```

Everything works fine, but I don't understand what the problem with the original line was. Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Comment: You should learn how to use pdb at least, or pudb. Or another debugger - it will help you a lot in cases like this. Also, try adding `print(id(curr_trav))` after your second line in your function.

Comment: I used pdb to step through and I know exactly *what's* happening, I just don't understand exactly *why* they're happening, and I think I just fundamentally misunderstand how python passes objects. So I was hoping someone one here could clear up my misunderstanding.

Comment: That's some information that could have been added to your question - explaining exactly *what* you observe is a pretty good way to understand why it's happening.

Comment: oh, I said that "it seems as if curr_trav += [node] is mutating the original list"; that's pretty much my entire problem. What else do you think I should add to clarify?

Comment: "seems" means you don't quite understand ;) When you run pdb, check the `id(curr_trav)`. Then you will *know* if it's modifying the underlying list. Then you can say what you did (ran pdb, checked the id, it *is* the same list, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of `+=` is not quite correct.  All operators in Python are really just shortcuts.  For example, `a + b` is `a.__add__(b)` if `a` has an `__add__` method.  If `a` does not, it is `b.__radd__(a)`.  If `b` doesn't have that method, an error is raised.  Usually, `a += b` behaves quite like `a = a + b`, but in the case of mutable objects, it usually doesn't.  That is because `a += b` is `a.__iadd__(b)` if `a` has the `__iadd__` method.  If `a` does not, it is the same as `a = a.__add__(b)`.  If `a` doesn't have that either, it is the same as `a = b.__radd__(a)`.  Since lists *do* have the `__iadd__` method, the actual list object is changed instead of redefining `curr_trav`.

Answer (score 4):

With python it is neither by value or reference. It is a combination of both, and depends on the type of object being passed into the function. For example if a mutable type such as `dict, list etc` is passed in it will pass the reference. Whereas with a immutable type such as a `str` it will be by value. A good read on this subject is by [Jeff Knupp](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).

The issue with your original code `curr_trav += [node]` is that it is adding the values of `[node]` to `curr_trav` and setting the reference to the new list. Because it passes the reference for `curr_trav` it will be changed through each subsequent iteration.

Comment: I've read that article, but I'm still confused why my particular case is behaving the way that it is.

Comment: I just read your edit - I'm still a confused, I thought python *doesn't* pass references?